# Simplest ElasticSearch query

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I have the following document:

```
obj = {
  "ID": 4,
  "GUID": 4,
  "Type": "Movie",
  "Type": "Margin Call",
}
```

Is there a simple "all-type" query that can be done, for example something like:

```
>>> es.search(index="avails", term="margin")
```

Or -

```
>>> es.search(index="avails", term="Movie")
```

Or -

```
>>> es.search(index="avails", term="4")
```

Or, do I need to use the specialized ElasticSearch syntax differently for each of these searches? Basically, I'm just looking to approximate results and make sure object-creation is working working digging into the query language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the simplest way I could figure out to do a search in ElasticSearch:

```
def search(self, index=None, **kwargs):
    """
    This will use the & syntax with all the kwargs provided.
    For example: es.search(name="margin", id=4) ==> ?name=margin&id=4.

    Use as a simplified search to gut check very basic things.
    """
    index = index or self.index
    qs = urllib.urlencode(kwargs)
    try:
        res = self.es.search(index=index, q=qs)
    except TransportError, e:
        print '>>>', e
        res = None
    return res
```